# For each of the following sets, determine whether 2 is an element of that set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

c) {2,{2}} 
d) {{2},{{2}}}

The answer for C is yes and d is No, 
However i still don't understand why the answer for c is yes and d is no

anyone know
thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of a set are separated by commas. In (C), you see that "$2$" is the first element, and "$\{2\}$" is the second element. However, the elements of (D) are "$\{2\}$" and "$\{\{2\}\}$" (which are sets), neither of which is simply the number $2$.